# android studio emulator error intel haxm is required but no virtualization in bios

Tags: android, haxm

I have an HP 500-277c Running Windows 10 64 bit with an i7-4770 CPU, the Intel specs say the CPU supports VT-x, VT-d, EPT, Execute Disable Bit
https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/75122/intel-core-i74770-processor-8m-cache-up-to-3-90-ghz.html

I have reviewed the system requirements at
https://github.com/intel/haxm/wiki/Windows-System-Configurations

The BIOS on my machine are incredibly simple, not much at all to them. There is nothing in them about enabling virtualization, or Execute Disable Bit.

I have tried to install HAXM through the android development studio and directly from intel (Intel HAXM V7.8.0). The installation process tells me

> The HAXM driver can be installed on this computer. However, it is
> required to further configure the system to make it useable. Then HAXM
> will be automatically loaded for use.

HAXM consistently tells me I need to configure

> BIOS/UEFI: Enable Intel Virtualization Technology

I have done everything possible on the HP website to update my bios. My bios is at 80.19 and there is no update available.

There is nowhere in my bios to enable virtualization.

HAXM will not run without virtualization.

The android emulators will not run without HAXM.

My question is how can I get an android emulator running?

Comment: Found the virtualization in the bios under System Security of all places, I have Virtualization Technology (VTx/VTd) enabled. The studio would not run with the verision of HAXM fron intel, I had to remove it, when reinstalling I get "VMX Supported: Yes, VMX enabled: No". My question remains, how can I get an android emulator running.